# C# System.OutOfMemmoryException in TCP Server

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, tcpserver

i have a multi-threaded TCP server that is written in C#. Clients are accepted by server and don't leave the server when they are connected. After approximately 1300 active connections, my software gives System.OutOfMemmoryException error. Does this problem related to 32 bit system architecture and ram? I have 32 bit Windows 7 Professional and 4 GBs RAM. When approximately 1300 active connections exist on my server, my memmory usage is about 2.1GB and CPU usage is 30%.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess...yes, anyway your applications won't see more than 2 GB of memory on a 32 bit architecture.

Comment: Do you have a thread-per-connection or do you use a pool of threads?

Comment: I do know he has the first one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.OutOfMemmoryException` is thrown when ~1300 threads in your process is created (at 32 bit OS). And the problem is that you are creating brand new thread for each connection. That is the bad practice.

You should instead use only one thread for managing the sending data, the same thread (or may be second) for sending it and only **one** for accepting connections.

Code example for the thread pool accepting all the clients:

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 90);

public void BeginAccept()
{
    try { tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptClient, null); }
    catch { /* Swallowing is bad */ }
}

private void AcceptClient(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient;

    try { tcpClient = tcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar); }
    catch { /* Swallowing is bad */ }
    finally { BeginAccept(); }

    // TODO: Add your brand new tcpClient to some sort of collection, may be.
}
```

Code example for one thread accepting all the clients:

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 90);
bool isListening;

public void BeginAccept()
{
    while (isListening)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient;

        try { tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient(); }
        catch { /* Swallowing is bad */ }

        // TODO: Add your brand new tcpClient to some sort of collection, may be.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I was just going to mention the threads! I think the default stack-size is 1mb

Comment: i think this is not possible because i want to open thread for every device. how can i use pool of threads?

Comment: I think everything is possible. What is the reason for keeping a thread for each device?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at implementing the [Asynchronous Server Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx).
I would still recommend to send responses in a different thread to avoid queues/TCP resends. 
 You may either use tasks or add the received messages with the related connections into a concurrrent queue with a working crew processing them.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer/OS is not the limiting factor. It can allocate nearly 4GB per process (if you use more than 4GB in total it will start swapping/writing to disk: that's much slower than regular memory but it will still work).
However, the C# compiler is limiting you. C# by default compiles for 32 bits and this means each process can only use about 2GB of memory. This is why your server crashes once it reaches 2GB.
You could compile it for a 64 bits OS which would allow you to use virtually unlimited memory, but you don't have a 64 bits OS so it would not run on your machine.

It is better to create a new process for each client connection, rather than a thread. Your main process would listen for and accept connections, and when a new connection is made it should spawn a new process dedicated solely to handling the connection with that client. Because each connection has its own process you will not hit the 2GB limit any more and there are many more advantages: once a connection is closed reclaiming the memory is much easier and any error in one connection would be less likely to crash the entire program.
Of course, programming for a multi-process architecture is somewhat harder than for a multi-threaded one since there is no shared memory but it is the better approach here.